# Responds to a request with an plain html page but does not load my static file

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have some html pages generated by an external tool.

Now I need to take this full html file with `.png` file, `.js` file and `.css` file and serve it.

I try

```py
path('rep/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="output/23062020_14_32_44/Report_TC_trial_test.html")) #in urls.py
#result: load html file but the other files do not
```

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.template import loader
def stet_report(request):
    template=loader.get_template('output/23062020_14_32_44/Report_TC_trial_test.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

```py
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
def stet_report(request):
    return render_to_response('output/23062020_14_32_44/Report_TC_trial_test.html')
```

The same results for all my attempts

As a mention, I am not allowed to modify the html file

Comment: maybe builtin flatpage would help

Comment: why do you think django will serve static files that are not in static directory https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/ , you probably want to serve this as static site using nginix, there is no point of using framework for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I want to mention that an html template / page loads separately.

First the html page is loaded and then the dependent files are loaded: `.png` `.svg` `.js` etc.

These fine below the url `/static/{your_file}` and template expression with `load static` and `static 'file_path'` works like a shortcut.

Finally I uploaded the html page or the `/rep/{id}` url

These pages in the url request static files in the form `rep/{file}`

So I added in `ulr.py`:

```py
from django.views import static
url(r'^rep/(?P<path>.*)$', static, {'document_root': settings.BASE_DIR + "/stetapp/static"}),
```

At this point everything was fine except that my `.js` files were detected as `text/plain`
on the line `content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(str(full_path))` and all I did was make a correction based on the extension of my file

```
content_type = 'application/javascript' if file_extension == '.js' else content_type or 'application/octet-stream'
```